# LibGdx: Loading purchase history without purchaseRestore()

Tags: libgdx

I use a database to store values when a user buys a product, for example when the user buys the full version, it is saved as value "1". I use Gdx-Pay for dealing with purchases.

I would like to avoid making a server-call every time I need to check if a user has bought a product or not, using purchaserestore is not really an option since apple does not allow it to run without the user pressing a button.

I was thinking of storing it in preferences on launch, that way I only need 1 servercall, but wouldnt that be really unsafe? anyone can just go to the pref-file and edit the value from "0" to "1", and my system will think they bought the product.

How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scramble that 0 or 1 somehow so nobody could figure out how it works.

If 'gadsfsr2fds2' means not bought what is the correct code for bought? :)

You can involve some device unique number in it so for every device zeros and ones will have different values.

Not bullet proof, but will repel 95% of "hackers".

Comment: Wouldnt that mean that all someone has to do is post the "scrambled" value online, and then anyone who knows how to edit prefs can use it?

Comment: That's why I said that you should involve (use as "salt") unique device number in this value generations so it would be different for every device.

Comment: I was thinking, wouldnt it be possible to just do a servercall to user db on startup, and have a variable called "hasBought" in the client, and if the user has value "1" (did buy) then we set hasBought=true. And then we can reach hasBought through the entire app lifecycle through ´game.getHasBought()´. This way you cant really cheat it.

Comment: That should be possible. I thought that you want to server even less frequently then per every game start.

Comment: Since its an online game we need to call it on launch anyway. Thanks for your help